# the SQL Server Query below returns (No Columny Name) in Column 4. How do I create a Column Name in column 4

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below below code, however I am running into an issue where I have been trying to rename the the column named "(No Problem Name").  I haven't figured out a solution to rename the colume "Effective Data".  Currently all I can get the column to read it "No Problem Here".

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ded.PlanYear  ,ded.BenefitType  ,ded.ProductID
     ,convert(datetime, ded.CoverageEffDate, 101) ,megp.GroupID 
 FROM DET_ENROLLMENT_DETAILS ded
 INNER JOIN MST_EMPLOYER_GROUP_PLAN megp ON ded.ProductID = megp.ProductID 
 WHERE 
     --ded.CoverageEffDate LIKE '%2019%'  ded.CoverageEffDate >= '2019-09-30'  AND  
     ded.BenefitType = 'MEDICAL'
```

Comment: Note that this happens whenever you use a function or expression in a SELECT return list column.  The returned column no longer has a default name, and so you have to assign an explicit one (as noted in the answers below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 4th column to start with [] =

```
[columnname] = convert(datetime, ded.CoverageEffDate, 101)
```

Inside the [] you can provide the name of the colum.

> Alternatively you can use AS:

```
convert(datetime, ded.CoverageEffDate, 101) AS ColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'AS name'

```
SELECT DISTINCT ded.PlanYear  ,ded.BenefitType  ,ded.ProductID
     ,convert(datetime, ded.CoverageEffDate, 101) AS 'convert', megp.GroupID 
 FROM DET_ENROLLMENT_DETAILS ded
 INNER JOIN MST_EMPLOYER_GROUP_PLAN megp ON ded.ProductID = megp.ProductID 
 WHERE 
 --ded.CoverageEffDate LIKE '%2019%'  ded.CoverageEffDate >= '2019-09-30'  AND  
 ded.BenefitType = 'MEDICAL'
```